# Storing booking items information in session array of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to store booking items such as

--> pid =1, qty=3

--> pid=5, qty=4
and so on

in codeigniter session.

I am finding it difficult and i am running out of deadline. Helping hands are very much appreciated.

Comment: Use Codeigniter Cart library if you're dealing with booking, otherwise just use pid as keys & qty as values or you'll have to store array of arrays to represent your data. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an example special for you. Suppouse it will helps

```
    $data = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
        $data[] = array('pid' => $i, 'qty' => $i);
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('order_data', $data);
```

and output your result will be shown in session like these :

```
[order_data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 1
                [qty] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 2
                [qty] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 3
                [qty] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 4
                [qty] => 4
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 5
                [qty] => 5
            )

    )
```

If you want to call only these data (booking data) then call

```
$this->session->userdata['order_data']
```

you can free use it in foreach for view like

```
foreach ($this->session->userdata['order_data'] as $key => $value)
{

}
```